# Find lowest period of a string (given array of string) to create a substring and return an array of integers

Tags: c#

So I was looking through interview questions that unfortunately didn't have any solutions, and one of them seemed interesting (mostly because I had no idea how to do it). However now I have hit a roadblock and am not sure how to proceed. The objective of the program is to take any amount of strings and spit out the periods of the lowest repeated characters to form the substring in an integer array.

Ex: "abbabbabba","abcdabcddabcdabc","aeiouuaeioouaei" would be 5, 8, 5.

I kind of looked at it as doing Indian runs. The first character runs to the front, if it equals the next character than continue running, etc.

This is the code I have compiled and I tried to take a look at the algorithm for finding periods as well (http://monge.univ-mlv.fr/~mac/REC/text-algorithms.pdf#page=345). I just can't seem to pinpoint the problem in the code

```
namespace Interview36{

public class PeriodicStrings
{
    public static int[] process(string[] input)
    {
        if (input == null || input.Length == 0 || input[0].Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result is null");
        }
        int length = 0;
        int[] list = new int[input.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) {

            while (i < input[i].Length)
            {
                if (input[i] == input[length])
                {
                    length++;
                    list[i] = length;
                    i++;
                }

                else
                {
                    if (length != 0)
                    {
                        length = list[length - 1];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        list[i] = 0;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

}

My best guess is that my logic is WAY off, or the loop isn't running through properly and I'm just not catching it in debug. Thank you in advance for any insight!

Comment: am sorry if am being dumb, but could you explain how shortest repeated string in "abbabbabba" is 5 ?

Comment: What are the string values that are found for `5, 8, 5`.

Comment: Not being dumb at all! So essentially: abbab --> babba; so it takes 5 characters to make the whole string (or a five character substring). It confused me too with how it was written. The way I see it is that the second part of the substring starts with the last character of the first one. From what I can tell there is no way to parse it at all in a way for me to pick it up by individual characters.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I'm not sure if I understand the question? 5,8,5 is the k period for the whole string. So it takes 5 characters to make the first string, 8 for the next, 5 for the last and they're repeated with the last character of the first coming forward.

Comment: *it takes 5 characters to make the first string*... it seems like it only takes 2 `a` and `b`...

Comment: Sorry - it takes at least 5 characters to make the repeated substring: so for the first string "abbabbabba" --> "abbab" + "babba"; If 'ab' was the substring it would not be able to form the 'bb' in the string. I don't know it that helps? (It took me forever to pick up on how it works....)

Comment: @Jill, I read the problem as: What is the lowest substring in the string which is not repeated? Take the first: a is repeated, ab is repeated, abb is ..., abba is...., abbab is not repeated. It seems the problem only takes the start substring into account..

Comment: @Aldert Hmmmm maybe I should try to use the Z-function then and iterate through the loop that way. I believe it deals better with string compression.